# Demo versus Prototype

Tags: prototyping

What are the differences between a demo and a prototype in software engineering?

My research taught me that a prototype is typically the minimum viable software needed to allow users to test its functionality.

Please provide an example to clarify the differences.

Comment: There is no trademark or patent on these terms, and the boundaries between them are fuzzy. Don't trust answers when they miss to mention this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A demo is a presentation of results. A result is not necessarily a product or even a complete feature. It just demonstrates progress.

A prototype is a product that is expected to need more work (or may even be a dummy) but will allow stakeholders to see what the end result will (or is planned to) be like.